# Save date read from date picker in plist file ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

How i can choose date formate (yyyy/mm/dd) from picker and save it in plist file?
and how i can implement the plist file? i am beginner to ios development and need to save date in file to make on it some calculation.

Comment: Why save to a file in order to perform calculations? And if you want to save a date to a file, why a plist?

Comment: thanks for your replay but i need the user to enter specific date and i need it to make calculation
its not necessary to save it on file? or what where i must save it? if i dont save it on db or file how i can treat with date and use it?

Comment: " i am beginner to ios development and need to save date" - quite straightforward solution: google it and/or read Apple's docs.

Comment: Also, Xcode doesn't have the slightest relation to iOS development. Furthermore, that's "thanks a lot" and not "allot", but you shouldn't be cluttering your posts with "hi" and "thanks" anyway.

Comment: thanks H2CO3 for your comments you help me over than i expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implemented UIDatePicker functionality. 
e.g. You have already UIDatePicker * datePicker.
1. save date to plist(use Documents folder)

```
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Create name of file:

```
    NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPlistFile.plist"];
```

Save date via NSDictionary:

```
        NSDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[datePicker date] forKey:@"date"];
```

Write dictionary to file:

```
        [dict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Then you can get saved date from file:

```
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSDate * savedDate = [dic objectForKey:@"date"];
```

Create date(formate(yyyy/mm/dd)):

```
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter new] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy/MM/dd"];
NSString * strSavedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:savedDate];
```

Comment: One thing that's probably nice to mention is that this works because `NSDate` conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: ok thank you gaRik but the date plist file shod contains what? year as array and other row for month as array and day as array or just one line for date as whole???

Comment: i am use your code and its success but i ake plist file contains <dict>
 <key>Date</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
and the date which i choose it saving in plist is it correct because i need to make calculation on day+7 , month-3 and year-1 can i make this calculation?